# How can i fix Error '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter

**I have json object register  i'ts has  abject user and token  .So when make register I need saving token and id  ..that  token  I can saved but the id  I can't it's showing me Error**

> '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type
>   'String'

**So I need to access the user after that saving id
…How can I do it**

**this my json**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "user": {
        "name": "ahmed",
        "phone": "203025628",
        "password": "$2y$10$ksxsdQvsnwkgiAa2iBy8yumlMLC.gEfeKlBIIpNhGIGgX0.MoWyfO",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-18 18:01:09",
        "created_at": "2020-03-18 18:01:09",
        "id": 562
    },
    "token": "Example token ………. "
}
```

**function saving and function register API**

```
  _save(String token) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final key = 'user';

    final value = user;

    prefs.setString(key, value);

 }




regsiterdata(body) async {
   String url ='register';
   String fullURL = Serveurl+url;


   final response = await http.post(fullURL,body:body,
     headers: {
       'Accept':'application/json'
     },
   );

   status = response.body.contains('error');

   var data = json.decode(response.body);

   if (status) {
     print('data: ${data[response.statusCode]}');
     print('data: ${data["error"]}');

   } else {


     _save(data["user"]);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a `Map` where you need to use a `String`. You should tell us which line this exception is pointing to. There, convert the map to a string with the code below:

```
    final value = jsonEncode(user);
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html

Comment: did you understand what i need  i need to save id in json to function SharedPreferences how can i do it

Comment: is this the line with the issue? `prefs.setString(key, value);`

Comment: Yes this is line How can i solution